# send variable from ctivity to another one

Tags: android, variables, android-activity, send

I would like to send variable from ctivity to another activity, but these activities are not related directely. Infact, there is 3 or 4 activities running between them.

The variable that I would like to send is the ID of the user.

I tried with creating an intent between the two activities but it did not work.
Kindly help me :)

Comment: If there are many activities between the two you can either use a singleton or pass the ID in the all the intents that happen between the two activities.

Comment: see this post

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960849/using-integers-strings-etc-in-other-activities][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960849/using-integers-strings-etc-in-other-activities

Answer (score 0):

The "ID of the user" should be part of your data model. Your data model should be centrally accessible from all of your activities -- activities do not pass the data model to other activities. Whether you use a singleton (as one commenter suggested), or a persistent store (e.g., database), or a `ContentProvider` wrapped around a persistent store, is up to you.

Comment: @AyaAndro, Probably this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables