# Using Integers, Strings etc in other Activities

Tags: android

I've got two Activities. In one I calculate some things and therefore I have some Integers and also some Strings stored. So now I would like to use these Stings and Integers in my second Activity. How an I use them in my second Activity?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gotta pass them to your second activity.

When you create `Intent` to start activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
```

do extra step like this

```
i.putExtra("integer", myInteger); //where myInteger is integer you have in first Activity
i.putExtra("string", myString); //where myString is String you have in first Activity

startActivity(i);
```

and now in second Activity to access those values use following code

```
int in = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("integer");
String str = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("string");
```

as simple as that

Comment: glad to help, please read some examples or do some digging before posting your question next time. People don't like when simple questions are posted that have been answered many times before and they tend to down vote.